# How to remove first dot from a list of file paths

Tags: bash

I need to calculate the md5sum of one string per line in my `ls` dump:

directory_listing.txt:

```
./r/g4/f1.JPG
./r/g4/f2.JPG
./r/g4/f3.JPG
./r/g4/f4.JPG
```

However the md5sum should be calculated without the 'first dot'. I've written a simple script so far:

```
while read line
do
echo $line | exec 'md5sum'
done

./g.sh < directory_listing.txt
```

How can I remove the first dot from each line?

Comment: Why not just generate the file without it in the first place?

Comment: that file was not generated by me, so i cant.

Comment: `exec` isn't doing anything useful here -- just use `echo "${line#./}" | md5sum`.

Answer (score 8):

```
$ foo=./abc/123
$ echo "${foo#./}"
abc/123
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
echo $line | exec 'md5sum'
```

to:

```
echo $line | cut -c 2- | exec 'md5sum'
```